# MVC 5 How to pass ViewBag value to crystal report as parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, crystal-reports

Hi I am working with MVC 5 and crystal report but i have small problem :

in controller I called string Fname
in view I see it by `@ViewBage.fname = Fname`

the result for example Hussain as student name.

in crystal report parameter :

`rp.SetParameterValue("Fname","Hussain");`

The report is working fine
but I want to replace "Hussain" with ViewBage value I tried `("Fname", Fname)` not working.
`("Fname", ViewBage.fname)` not working

so please help how I can pass ViewBag value to crystal report parameter??

Answer (score 0):

You must use the parameter name as it is known within Crystal as the first argument.

Open the report in Crystal Designer. Find out what is the parameter name.

Comment: it is Fname and the column name is fname .